# How to add values in a string of type System.String in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, window

Problem Description:
I am trying to do the task mentioned here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182483/advent-of-code-2017-day-1-sum-of-digits-matching-the-next-digit-circular-list

But in Windows Power Shell using simple loop logic (as I am new to Power Shell)

The task requires to review a sequence of digits and find the sum of all digits that match the next digit in the list. The list is circular, so the digit after the last digit is the first digit in the list. For example:

> 1122 produces a sum of 3 (1 + 2) because the first digit 1 matches the second digit and the third digit 2 matches the fourth digit; 1111
>   produces 4 because each digit (all 1) matches the next; 
>   1234 produces 0 because no digit matches the next; 
>   91212129 produces 9 because the only digit that matches the next one is the last digit, 9

I have coded this:

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("./task1.txt"))
{
    $data = ($line)
}

$i=0
Do 
{    
if ($data[$i] -eq $data[$i+1]) {    
$final += $data[$i]
}

$i++    
}
While ($i -le $data.Length)

($final | Measure-Object -Sum).sum
```

My "task1.txt" contains the value - "1122"

The $final is storing the value "12" these digits are expected but I am unable to sum them up to get the desired answer - "3"

When I try to use:

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("./task1.txt"))
{
    [int[]]$data = [int[]]$line.split('')


}
```

My "$data" gets the entire "1122" as a value

Please help!

Comment: Treat $data as a string and iterate through it's Length with the [index] or .Substring() method

Comment: `$line.split('')` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Casting to a string array before casting to an int array would likely work. e.g. `[int[]][string[]]$line`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The var $i iterates through the Length,

**Edit** streamlined version thank to a hint from [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788803/benh)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\17\SO_50397884.ps1
function CodeAdvent2017-1 {
    param ([string]$data)
    $res = 0
    for ($i=0;$i -le $data.Length-1;$i++){
        if ($data[$i] -eq $data[$i-1]){
            $res+=[int]$data.substring($i,1)
        }
        #"`$i={0}, `$pnt={1} `$data[`$i]={2} `$res={3}" -f $i,$pnt,$data[$i],$res
    }
    return "Result: {0} of {1}" -f $res, $data
}

CodeAdvent2017-1 1122       #produces 3
CodeAdvent2017-1 1111       #produces 4
CodeAdvent2017-1 1234       #produces 0
CodeAdvent2017-1 91212129   #produces 9
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\05\17\SO_50397884.ps1
Result: 3 of 1122
Result: 4 of 1111
Result: 0 of 1234
Result: 9 of 91212129
```

Comment: Rather than using modulus you could also look behind since `[0]` and `[0-1]` would compare with the last value.

Comment: @LotPings Awesome! Thanks a lot. But, could you please explain me what "-1" is doing in the function "CodeAdvent2017-1". And how the you are checking the last digit and the first digit? I am little confused there.

Comment: @LotPings
Adding my code below but need to understand your answer :)
Also, In my code If I want to provide file-name as a parameter when calling my .ps1 file how to do that? Any Idea

Comment: @Alex `CodeAdvent2017-1` is just the name of the function, `-` is valid character in a function name. As for comparing the first and the last digit, in PowerShell if you use `[-1]` as an index it references the end of the array. So `@('a','b','c')[-1]` is `c`. So by using by comparing `$i` and `$i-1` when `$i` is 0 then it compares index `0` and `-1` which is the first and the last elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($line in (gc ".\task1")) {
    [string]$data = $line   
}

$i=0
$final = 0
Do {
    if ($data[$i] -eq $data[$i -1]) {
        $final += [int]$data.substring($i,1)
    }
    $i++    
} While ($i -le $data.Length-1)

$final
```

Comment: Your try was overyl complicated, changed above.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.